# MongoDB fetching long arrays is slow

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

So we have lists of 2000 to 100,000 items in an array that's in mongo. I want to pull that out to use.

The explain shows that it's using the index and only scanning 1 document.  But it takes 1.5 - 3 seconds to run. I assume because of the large arrays. Is there anway to speed that up? I feel stuck there.

Here is the query

```
db.monitors.find({userId: "xxxx"})
```

And here is the explain

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "xx.monitors",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "userId" : {
                "$eq" : "xxx"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "userId" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "user",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "userId" : [ 
                        "[\"xxx\", \"xxx\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 2,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 1,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 2,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "userId" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "user",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "userId" : [ 
                        "[\"xxx\", \"xxx\"]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : []
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "xx",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.0.4",
        "gitVersion" : "0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5"
    }
}
```

Comment: `userId` field is the array?

Comment: It is going to be slow. I recall a user group discussion with a visting member of MongoDB NYC office. In the dicussion a general statement was that arrays beyond 500 elements show a significant degradation in performance. If you have arrays with 2,000 to 100,000 items you should probably be using a separate collection for those items instead.

Comment: `monitors.xyz` is the array. So `monitors.dog`, `monitors.animal.`

Comment: The goal here is that we are scanning thousands of articles, and then adding those IDs to the monitor keywords that people have setup. So someone might care about dogs, so they set the word dog. 5000 articles might have that word. These documents are grouped by userId

Comment: and the reason that we shouldn't make a document `{userId, term, article_id}` is because that would make the "set" very slow. You'd have to query to get all the IDs, then add things to the set, then upsert + multi to insert all those documents

Comment: The comments would have been better off as an edit to your question, with just a comment to alert of the changes. However, rather than saying  "we don't do that because..", then how about actually setting up the data in an alternate way and benchmark testing. Unless you have already done that and know it is slower.